# Взять текст и вставить в переменную

Tags: python, api, tkinter

Ввод API ключа в текстовое поле, сохранить его в переменную, после нажатия на кнопку получить - подставить его и получить данные с сервера.

Работает, только если явно определяю: API_KEY='ключ'

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import requests
import json
 
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.title("API mpoisk.ru")

l1 = Label(root, text = "Ваш ключ API")
l1.config(font = ("Courier", 14))


l = Label(root, text = "Результат")
l.config(font = ("Courier", 14))


T = Text(root, height = 15, width = 40)
T.tag_configure("bold", font="Arial 8 bold")

T1 = Text(root, height = 20, width = 50)
T.tag_configure("bold", font="Arial 8 bold")

def get_api():
    API_KEY = T1.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    
API_KEY = T1.get("1.0",'end-1c')


header = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + API_KEY,
}
api_url ="здесь ссылка"

def get_fact1():
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=header)
    response_info = json.loads(response.text)
    Fact = response_info
    T.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    T.insert(tk.END, Fact)   

b = Button(root, text = "Авторизоваться", command = get_api)
b1 = Button(root, text = "Получить", command = get_fact1)

l1.pack()
T1.pack()
b.pack()

l.pack()
T.pack()

b1.pack()
b2.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_api():
    API_KEY = T1.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    
header = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + API_KEY,
}
```

Тут сразу две проблемы:

1. Для функции `get_api` переменная `API_KEY` - **локальная**. Вы можете написать в неё что угодно, вне этой функции значение **глобальной** переменной `API_KEY` не поменяется.
2. Пользуясь значением переменной `API_KEY` вы задали значение словаря `header` один раз, в начале работы кода, и больше его никак не меняете. Даже если вы поменяете значение `API_KEY`, оно не попадёт автоматически в словарь `header.

Лучше всего исправить эту ситуацию так на мой взгляд:

```
def get_api():
    return T1.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    
def get_header():
    return {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + get_api() }

api_url ="здесь ссылка"

def get_fact1():
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=get_header())
```

В этом случае `header` будет формироваться динамически, используя текущее значение ключа из соответствующего поля. А кнопка `'Авторизоваться'` вообще не нужна.

Нет, можно решить и как вы хотите, но тогда нужно сохранять **глобальную** переменную `API_KEY` и всё-равно формировать `header` динамически. Глобальные переменные - не очень хорошее решение, поэтому я это решение не рекомендую:

```
def get_api():
    global API_KEY
    API_KEY = T1.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    
def get_header():
    return {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + API_KEY }

api_url ="здесь ссылка"

def get_fact1():
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=get_header())
```

В методе `get_header` указывать, что `API_KEY` это глобальная переменная не нужно. Без записи, только при чтении, переменная считается глобальной автоматически. Проблемы с областью видимости начинаются, когда вы именно что-то пишете в переменную внутри функции.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, что уделили время и помогли. Всё работает. Спасибо.